# Multiple localisable strings referring to a common shared string

Tags: ios

There are several places in my GUI where the same string is used, however to make things easier for translators and testers to reference, and also to allow for the future possibility that the strings might change in different places I would like to do something like the following in the localization file:

```
"SHARED_DIALOG_TEXT" = "Shared in several places";
"DIALOG_A" = "SHARED_DIALOG_TEXT";
"DIALOG_B" = "SHARED_DIALOG_TEXT";
"DIALOG_C" = "SHARED_DIALOG_TEXT";
```

Obviously this won't work and I'm using it for illustrative purposes of what I'd like to do.
Is a resource referring to an earlier resource possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do this that could work for you. It's not 100% pure resource based, but it's the closest you'll get to what you're looking to do.

Use the localization macro `NSLocalizedStringFromTable()`. This takes three parameters:

1. The string to localize
2. The table name, which is just a file name
3. The comment, just like in `NSLocalizedString()`

If you use a table name then you can have another strings file for shared strings or separate ones for changes later, e.g. if I do `NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"string", @"SharedStrings", @"comment");` then put my strings in a `SharedStrings.strings` file it will use that.

Then if you override the translation later, just use a different 'table' file for the overrides when needed. `NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"string", @"NewOverride", @"comment");`

Good Luck With Your Project!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
"SHARED_DIALOG_TEXT" = "Shared in several places";
"DIALOG_A" = "%@";
"DIALOG_B" = "%@";
"DIALOG_C" = "%@";

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"DIALOG_C"), NSLocalizedString(@"SHARED_DIALOG_TEXT")];
```

Comment: Thanks, but if DIALOG_C text were to change, it would mean a code change rather than just a resource file change. Is there any resource file only solution?